# Converting one UNICODE character to two ASCII ones

Tags: python, c++, unicode, ascii

I have an `unsigned int`. In python I've seen when I try to input a UNICODE character into usual string, characters output normally, but they are 2 characters in raw string output. How to convert `unsigned int` to 2 `char`?

For example

file.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

str = "Ю" # That's a unicode character
print str # It outputs normally
print str[0] # It does some output kinda '\xd0'
```

Comment: You may be interested reading about [`std::wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: I have already read about it, but I want to learn more about converting.

Comment: Can you give any example? I'm sry but I didn't got the question.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what conversion you wish to perform

Comment: Joel Spolsky's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) might give you hints on what exactly to ask for.

Comment: `"Ю"` is a bytestring in Python 2 (it is not Unicode). Unrelated: `str` is builtin name, don't replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, a thing I wanted to do is to convert unicode to utf-8